# When popping , Why do we need to pass a context to Navigator in flutter?

Tags: flutter, reactive-programming, flutter-layout

Since flutter uses a stack to manage the screens which can be accessed through the Navigator class , I have the below understanding of it :

When we do Navigator.push(`context` , ... )  :  Here the `context` is used so that it knows on top of which other widget it should push the new screen.

What I don't understand is why it needs a context to pop a screen out of view ?

Can't it simply pop the top most screen of the stack and show the screen below that ?

`What exactly is the role of context here` and how does it differ when `pushing` and `popping`

Comment: tried to "Ctrl + left click" on `Navigator.push(..)` method?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the same for both `push` and `pop` - it's to *find* the `Navigator`.

Looking at `.pop` you see that it's a static, convenience function that does:

```
  return Navigator.of(context).pop<T>(result);
```

The `context` is used in `.of` to locate the navigator in the widget tree above the widget where you are calling push or pop. As you'd expect, `of` (another static convenience function) locates the actual navigator using:

```
 context.findAncestorStateOfType()
```

So, in summary, you pass context so that `context.findAncestor...` can be used to find the navigator on which to call the method.